# How to install TBB from source on Linux and make it work

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, installation, tbb

I would like to know how to install TBB from source and make it work on a Linux system.  I have had some problems when it comes using it, problems that don't appear if I install TBB via the package manager.

In the TBB webpage, there are some guidelines on how about to do this, like setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `CPATH` variables, or sourcing the `tbbvars.sh` file. Even if I do that, when I try to compile an example `g++` says that `tbb` is not found.

So my question is, is there an easy way to setup everything (compile the source code, what variables should I set...) in order to use TBB?

Thanks.

**NOTE:** The library version number when this question was asked was 2 (if I recall correctly). I have personally tested the solution up to version 4.1, but I think it should work too for current version `4.2 (update 3)` since the building method remains the same.

Comment: What did you try already? Is there any documentation for TBB? And most important: What **is** TBB? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Gnosophilon You can move your mouse over the tag and find out what TBB is

Comment: ./configure; make; sudo make install

Comment: Worth noting that in Ubuntu 19.10, it all works after one `sudo apt install`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031060/are-c17-parallel-algorithms-implemented-already/55989883#55989883

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I have come with the solution. I'll post it here so it will help others with this topic.

1. Download the latest stable source code and uncompress it, i.e in `~/tbbsrc`
2. Inside, type `make`. It should start compiling the tbb library and the memory allocators.
3. The headers are in `~/tbbsrc/include`
4. Inside `~/tbbsrc/build` will be two new folders, one for the release version and the other for the debug version. Those folders are named like `architecture_ldVersion_g++Version_kernelVersion`.
5. I recommend setting some variables, for example in your `~/.bashrc` file, like:

```
TBB_INSTALL_DIR = $HOME/tbbsrc
TBB_INCLUDE = $TBB_INSTALL_DIR/include
TBB_LIBRARY_RELEASE = $TBB_INSTALL_DIR/build/RELEASE_FOLDER
TBB_LIBRARY_DEBUG = $TBB_INSTALL_DIR/build/DEBUG_FOLDER
```

6. Let's try a simple example:

```
// main.cpp
#include "tbb/task_scheduler_init.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // tbb::task_scheduler_init init(tbb::task_scheduler_init::automatic);
    // implicit tbb::task_sheduler_init::automatic
    tbb::task_scheduler_init init;
    return 0;
}
```

7. To compile, for example, with the release version:

```
g++ main.cpp -I$TBB_INCLUDE -Wl,-rpath,$TBB_LIBRARY_RELEASE -L$TBB_LIBRARY_RELEASE -ltbb
```

> Note: with `-Wl,-rpath,$TBB_LIBRARY_RELEASE`, we are telling the dynamic linker where to find `libtbb.so`

8. And that should work fine!

Best regards!

**Installation for Apple clang 5.1:** [thanks to rwols for the info]

Instead of typing `make`, type `make compiler=clang` or `make compiler=clang stdlib=libc++`

Comment: Yeah. Thats why you have to pass it with `-Wl`, so the linker "recognize it". This was tested both in Ubuntu and Windows with `g++ 4.4` and `g++ 4.7`. I haven't tested it with newer versions.

Comment: but isn't -W1 an option just providing info for warning? I did not write that option so I am curious... :)

Comment: Or... wait it is not W1 but Wl... l as "linker"!!! Yeah! Understood!!! Sorry and thank you very much

Comment: lol. It's tricky eh? I also have problems telling them apart :D

Comment: When you're on Apple clang version 5.1, instead of typing `make`, type `make compiler=clang` or `make compiler=clang stdlib=libc++`.

Comment: @rwols Thanks for the info. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: It's strange that `make install` isn't supported.

Answer (score 11):

https://github.com/wjakob/tbb seems to be the way to go.

```
git clone https://github.com/wjakob/tbb.git
cd tbb/build
cmake ..
make -j
sudo make install
```

Comment: Thanks!  Much easier than Intel's git distribution, which has no install.  I suggest also running "make test" though, just in case.

Comment: This installed, but my runtime then expects to find libtbb.so.2 which is missing.

Comment: I fixed the missing file by adding the following line to `/etc/ld.so.conf`: `/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/tbb/lib/` and then calling `ldconfig`.