# cannot find -ltbb in eclipse Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

Tags: c++, tbb

I am trying to use TBB in eclipse ide c++. I installed the `TBB` by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libtbb-dev
```

Now when I try to build the code, i get the following error

```
make all 
Building target: AlignmentUnordParallel26_02_18
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++ -std=c++17 -static -L/home/ahussain/boost_1_65_1/stage/lib -o "AlignmentUnordParallel26_02_18"  ./TBB.o ./parallel_index.o   -lboost_serialization -ltbb
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltbb
makefile:44: recipe for target 'AlignmentUnordParallel26_02_18' failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [AlignmentUnordParallel26_02_18] Error 1
```

Saying that it could not find -ltbb. What is going wrong?

Comment: I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726537/how-to-install-tbb-from-source-on-linux-and-make-it-work) answer might come handy to you.

Comment: Hard to say. Where does the installer put libtbb on on your computer? You might to add the library path to the Library Paths tab on Properties->C/C++ General->Paths And Symbols.

Comment: @user4581301 I tried by building from the source and including the path `Building target: AlignmentUnordParallel26_02_18
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++ -std=c++17 -static -L/home/ahussain/boost_1_65_1/stage/lib -L/home/ahussain/tbb/tbb-2018_U2/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc5.4.0_libc2.23_kernel4.4.0_release -o "AlignmentUnordParallel26_02_18"  ./TBB.o ./parallel_index.o   -lboost_serialization -ltbb
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltbb
makefile:44: recipe for target 'AlignmentUnordParallel26_02_18' failed collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make: ** [AlignmentUnordParallel26_02_18] Error 1`

Comment: @user4581301 I am using `Cross G++ Linker g++`, do I need to have `gcc`