# Are C++17 Parallel Algorithms implemented already?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, g++, c++17, clang++

I was trying to play around with the new parallel library features proposed in the C++17 standard, but I couldn't get it to work. I tried compiling with the up-to-date versions of `g++ 8.1.1` and `clang++-6.0` and `-std=c++17`, but neither seemed to support `#include <execution>`, `std::execution::par` or anything similar.

When looking at the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/parallelism) for parallel algorithms there is a long list of algorithms, claiming

> Technical specification provides parallelized versions of the following 69 algorithms from `algorithm`, `numeric` and `memory`: *( ... long list ...)*

which sounds like the algorithms are ready *'on paper'*, but not ready to use yet?

In [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567998/how-do-i-use-the-new-c17-execution-policies) from over a year ago the answers claim these features hadn't been implemented yet. But by now I would have expected to see some kind of implementation. Is there anything we can use already?

Comment: Seems to be that MSVC is the only major compiler that supports these features, see [here](https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/06/parstl-tests.html).

Comment: I'm looking for those features for g++ aswell but it doesn't seem to be planned yet...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can refer [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/17) to check all `C++17` feature implementation status. For your case, just search `Standardization of Parallelism TS`, and you will find only `MSVC` and `Intel C++` compilers support this feature now.

Comment: I put together an open source repo, which works on MSVC, Intel and g++ 9.1 compilers, demonstrating usage and performance of parallel sort, along with a parallel merge sort (https://github.com/DragonSpit/ParallelAlgorithms)

Answer (score 50):

**GCC 9 has them but you have to install TBB separately**

In Ubuntu 19.10, all components have finally aligned:

- GCC 9 [is the default one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-on-ubuntu/1163021#1163021), and the minimum required version for TBB
- TBB (Intel Thread Building Blocks) is at 2019~U8-1, so it meets the minimum 2018 requirement

so you can simply do:

```
sudo apt install gcc libtbb-dev
g++ -ggdb3 -O3 -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.cpp -ltbb
./main.out
```

and use as:

```
#include <execution>
#include <algorithm>

std::sort(std::execution::par_unseq, input.begin(), input.end());
```

see also the full runnable benchmark below.

GCC 9 and TBB 2018 are the first ones to work as mentioned in the release notes: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/changes.html

> Parallel algorithms and `<execution>` (requires Thread Building Blocks 2018 or newer).

Related threads:

- [How to install TBB from source on Linux and make it work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726537/how-to-install-tbb-from-source-on-linux-and-make-it-work)
- [trouble linking INTEL tbb library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36534706/trouble-linking-intel-tbb-library)

**Ubuntu 18.04 installation**

Ubuntu 18.04 is a bit more involved:

- GCC 9 [can be obtained from a trustworthy PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-on-ubuntu/1163021#1163021), so it is not so bad
- TBB [is at version 2017](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libtbb-dev), which does not work, and I could not find a trustworthy PPA for it. Compiling from source is easy, but there is no install target which is annoying...

Here are fully automated tested commands for Ubuntu 18.04:

```
# Install GCC 9
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-9 g++-9

# Compile libtbb from source.
sudo apt-get build-dep libtbb-dev
git clone https://github.com/intel/tbb
cd tbb
git checkout 2019_U9
make -j `nproc`
TBB="$(pwd)"
TBB_RELEASE="${TBB}/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc7.4.0_libc2.27_kernel4.15.0_release"

# Use them to compile our test program.
g++-9 -ggdb3 -O3 -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -I "${TBB}/include" -L 
"${TBB_RELEASE}" -Wl,-rpath,"${TBB_RELEASE}" -o main.out main.cpp -ltbb
./main.out
```

**Test program analysis**

I have tested with this program that compares the parallel and serial sorting speed.

main.cpp

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <execution>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    using clk = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    decltype(clk::now()) start, end;
    std::vector<unsigned long long> input_parallel, input_serial;
    unsigned int seed;
    unsigned long long n;

    // CLI arguments;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint64_t> zero_ull_max(0);
    if (argc > 1) {
        n = std::strtoll(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    } else {
        n = 10;
    }
    if (argc > 2) {
        seed = std::stoi(argv[2]);
    } else {
        seed = std::random_device()();
    }

    std::mt19937 prng(seed);
    for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        input_parallel.push_back(zero_ull_max(prng));
    }
    input_serial = input_parallel;

    // Sort and time parallel.
    start = clk::now();
    std::sort(std::execution::par_unseq, input_parallel.begin(), input_parallel.end());
    end = clk::now();
    std::cout << "parallel " << std::chrono::duration<float>(end - start).count() << " s" << std::endl;

    // Sort and time serial.
    start = clk::now();
    std::sort(std::execution::seq, input_serial.begin(), input_serial.end());
    end = clk::now();
    std::cout << "serial " << std::chrono::duration<float>(end - start).count() << " s" << std::endl;

    assert(input_parallel == input_serial);
}
```

On Ubuntu 19.10, Lenovo ThinkPad P51 laptop with CPU: Intel Core i7-7820HQ CPU (4 cores / 8 threads, 2.90 GHz base, 8 MB cache), RAM: 2x Samsung M471A2K43BB1-CRC (2x 16GiB, 2400 Mbps) a typical output for an input with 100 million numbers to be sorted:

```
./main.out 100000000
```

was:

```
parallel 2.00886 s
serial 9.37583 s
```

so the parallel version was about 4.5 times faster! See also: [What do the terms "CPU bound" and "I/O bound" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868568/what-do-the-terms-cpu-bound-and-i-o-bound-mean/33510470#33510470)

We can confirm that the process is spawning threads with `strace`:

```
strace -f -s999 -v ./main.out 100000000 |& grep -E 'clone'
```

which shows several lines of type:

```
[pid 25774] clone(strace: Process 25788 attached
[pid 25774] <... clone resumed> child_stack=0x7fd8c57f4fb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7fd8c57f59d0, tls=0x7fd8c57f5700, child_tidptr=0x7fd8c57f59d0) = 25788
```

Also, if I comment out the serial version and run with:

```
time ./main.out 100000000
```

I get:

```
real    0m5.135s
user    0m17.824s
sys     0m0.902s
```

which [confirms again that the algorithm was parallelized since real < user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1/53937376#53937376), and gives an idea of how effectively it can be parallelized in my system (about 3.5x for 8 cores).

**Error messages**

Hey, Google, index this please.

If you don't have tbb installed, the error is:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/pstl/parallel_backend.h:14,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/pstl/algorithm_impl.h:25,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/pstl/glue_execution_defs.h:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/execution:32,
                 from parallel_sort.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/9/pstl/parallel_backend_tbb.h:19:10: fatal error: tbb/blocked_range.h: No such file or directory
   19 | #include <tbb/blocked_range.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

so we see that `<execution>` depends on an uninstalled TBB component.

If TBB is too old, e.g. the default Ubuntu 18.04 one, it fails with:

```
#error Intel(R) Threading Building Blocks 2018 is required; older versions are not supported.
```

Comment: It's specified here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.1.0/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017: _Note 3: The Parallel Algorithms have an external dependency on Intel TBB 2018 or later. If the `<execution>` header is included then `-ltbb` must be used to link to TBB._ It seems to be that parallel algorithms are implemented by Intel's Parallel STL: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/algorithm#L64, which itself requires TBB.

Comment: @DanielLangr thanks! The main question I had (lazy to research now ;-)) is: is TBB in-tree, if yes do I need to configure GCC build with any extra flags, otherwise how to install it on Ubuntu. I didn't know about `-ltbb` so that's a good start already :-) Then I'm going to benchmark something and give a graph here, it will be fun!

Comment: Parallel STL headers are now a part of libstdc++. They define a _parallel backend_ and [the only one supported is TBB](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/pstl/parallel_backend.h). The TBB backend header [requires TBB headers](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/pstl/parallel_backend_tbb.h). However, I cannot find TBB headers to be part of libstdc++. Therefore, it implies that not only linking the TBB library is required, but also providing TBB headers. Online demo supports it: https://wandbox.org/permlink/VSIcdvWCtTRko43Q.

Comment: BTW, I would prefer a standalone implementation of parallel STL algorithms than those from TBB. I extensively use parallel sorting and did a lot of experiments which generally revealed that the implementation of a parallel quicksort and mergesort from libstdc++ Parallel mode (PM) are superior to those from TBB. Unfortunately, PM is built upon OpenMP and its reimplementation by C++11 threads is anything but trivial.

Comment: @DanielLangr thanks for this info! You must be doing some fun stuff over there hehe ;-) I'll try to play around with this later on. If you have any open source benchmark code, do share a link.

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica BTW, I have now found that in Ubuntu 19.10 everything just works and updated the answer :-)

Answer (score 14):

Intel has released a Parallel STL library which follows the C++17 standard:

- https://github.com/intel/parallelstl

It is [being merged into GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2017-11/msg00112.html).

Answer (score 5):

Gcc does not yet implement the Parallelism TS (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017)

However libstdc++ (with gcc) has an experimental mode for some equivalent parallel algorithms.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode.html

Getting it to work:

> Any use of parallel functionality requires additional compiler and
>   runtime support, in particular support for OpenMP. Adding this support
>   is not difficult: just compile your application with the compiler flag
>   -fopenmp. This will link in libgomp, the GNU Offloading and Multi Processing Runtime Library, whose presence is mandatory.

Code example

```
#include <vector>
#include <parallel/algorithm>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v(100);

  // ...

  // Explicitly force a call to parallel sort.
  __gnu_parallel::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**2023 UPDATE**

Compiler and alternative library support for C++17 parallel algorithms:

|  | Linux | macOS | Windows |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GCC 8- | No | No | No |
| GCC 9+ | TBB Required | TBB Required | TBB Required |
| Clang (libstdc++) | TBB Required | TBB Required | TBB Required |
| Clang (libc++) | No | No | No |
| Apple Clang |  | No |  |
| MSVC 15.7+ (2017) |  |  | Yes |
| [Parallel STL](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/guide/get-started-with-parallel-stl.html) | TBB Required | TBB Required | TBB Required |
| [poolSTL](https://github.com/alugowski/poolSTL) | Yes* | Yes* | Yes* |

poolSTL does not implement all algorithms. However it is available as a single header file, so it's an easy backup to the other options.

MinGW is a strange one. Code using `std::execution::par` will compile and run, but performance is the same as sequential. I haven't found a reference to what the compiler actually supports (and why it's acting different from GCC), if anyone has insight please leave a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Gcc now support execution header, but not standard clang build from https://apt.llvm.org