# Using std::async and pass arguments in a vector to a function and gather results

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17, stdasync

I want to make this function to compute in parallel:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int compute_something(int i, int j) {
    return i*j;
}

int main() {

    auto params = std::vector<int>(1000,5);
    std::vector<int> results;
    for (auto i : params)
        results.push_back(compute_something(i,4));

    return 0;
}
```

I pass arguments from a list to a function and want the results returned in order. I want to use asynchronous parallelization, since `compute_something()` will take different times, depending on the input. Also the input vector is much larger than the number of cores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++17 the standard algorithms are available in a parallel version. You specify the [execution policy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t) (`std::seq`), parallel (`std::par`), or parallel and vectorised (`std::par_unseq`), and it will do the multithreading for you in the background.

So for what you want to do you can make use of [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with a lambda function to capture the operation you want to perform on every element of your input vector, and the results are put in the `results` vector (size has to be same):

```
#include <execution>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int compute_something(int i, int j) {
    return i * j;
}

int main()
{
    auto params = std::vector<int>(1000, 5);
    std::vector<int> results(1000, 0);
    std::transform(std::execution::par_unseq, params.begin(), params.end(),
        results.begin(), [](int i) { return compute_something(i, 4); }
    );
}
```

Of course, it is possible embed the computation within lambda for such a simple calculation as you have in `compute_something`. Then the code becomes:

```
std::transform(std::execution::par_unseq, params.begin(), params.end(),
        results.begin(), [](int i) { return i * 4; }
```

---

Not all compilers have implemented execution policy yet. So if your compiler doesn't support it you can do it another way: use [`std::async`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/async/) and process the input vector in chunks. To do this you would have to define a new function that takes iterators and returns result vector. Then you can combine the results at the end.

Example:

```
#include <future>
#include <vector>

using Iter = std::vector<int>::iterator;

std::vector<int> parallel_compute(Iter beg, Iter end)
{
    std::vector<int> results;
    //Reserve memory to avoid reallocations
    auto size = std::distance(beg, end);
    results.reserve(size);

    for (Iter it = beg; it != end; ++it)
    {
        results.push_back(*it * 4); //Add result to vector
    }

    return results;
}

int main()
{
    const int Size = 1000;
    //Chunk size
    const int Half = Size / 2;
    //Input vector
    auto params = std::vector<int>(Size, 5);
    //Create futures
    auto fut1 = std::async(std::launch::async, parallel_compute, params.begin(), params.begin()+ Half);
    auto fut2 = std::async(std::launch::async, parallel_compute, params.begin()+ Half, params.end());
    //Get results
    auto res1 = fut1.get();
    auto res2 = fut2.get();
    //Combine results into one vector
    std::vector<int> results;
    results.insert(results.end(), res1.begin(), res1.end());
    results.insert(results.end(), res2.begin(), res2.end());
}
```

The `launch::async` policy will ensure two threads are created. However, I wouldn't create too many threads - one per core is a reasonable strategy. You could make use of [`std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency) to get number of concurrent threads supported by system. Creating threads and managing them introduces some overhead and can be counterproductive if you create too many.

---

**Edit:**

To avoid expensive allocations for individual small vectors, we can create a result vector at the start and pass iterators to the result range for each parallel invocation of `parallel_compute`. Since each thread will be accessing a different part of the result vector, we don't need synchronisation:

```
#include <future>
#include <vector>

using Iter = std::vector<int>::iterator;

void parallel_compute(Iter beg, Iter end, Iter outBeg)
{
    for (Iter it = beg; it != end; ++it)
    {
        *outBeg++ = (*it * 4); //Add result to vector
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int Size = 1000;
    //Chunk size
    const int Half = Size / 2;
    //Input vector
    auto params = std::vector<int>(Size, 5);
    //Output vector
    std::vector<int> results(Size, 0);
    //Create futures
    auto fut1 = std::async(std::launch::async, parallel_compute, params.begin(), params.begin() + Half, results.begin());
    auto fut2 = std::async(std::launch::async, parallel_compute, params.begin() + Half, params.end(), results.begin() + Half);
    //Get results
    fut1.wait();
    fut2.wait();
}
```

Comment: Lambda could directly use the computation instead of calling that free function and with `auto` i.e. `[](const auto i) { return i * 4; }`.

Comment: @Azeem Yes, for a simple calculation as we have you can embed the logic within the lambda. I leave that to OP.

Comment: I am having problems compiling the code. I'm using MinGW-w64 on Win10. Does it support the "execution library"?

Comment: @JakeB. Actually not all compilers support execution policies yet as its a relatively new feature. Try adding the compiler option `-std=c++17`. I've got MS VS2019 and it does support it. You might find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031060/are-c17-parallel-algorithms-implemented-already

Comment: @JakeB. I've added an alternative solution if you can't use execution policy with your compiler.

Comment: I cannot get <algorithm> to load under Linux nor Windows. Thank you for your alternative solution, but the problem is that if some tasks finish way before others, then the core has to wait for the slow one to finish. I would like to feed the waiting core as soon as it finishes

Comment: @JakeB. Actually for the second solution you don't need `#include <algorithm>`, so I have removed that, but I'm very surprised you don't have that header. That's part of the standard library. You have to check your installation. Sorry I can't help there. As for your other question about some task finishing before another. Yes, that can happen. But they are running in parallel, so overall that should be faster (not accounting for thread creation,etc). You're only merging the results at the end.

Comment: @JakeB. hint: look for dynamic load balancing and work stealing