# C++ compiler support for std::execution (parallel STL algorithms)

Tags: c++, c++17, std

I wanted to use the parallel version of `std::sort` where I can specify an execution policy like `std::execution::par_unseq`.

I'm currently using `clang++-10` and `g++ 7.5.0` under Ubuntu Linux, but both don't find the required include file `execution`, so apparently the parallel algorithm is not yet supported in these compiler versions.

Can someone please tell me which version of `clang` and `gcc` would support this feature?

Comment: libstdc++ 9, not in libc++ yet: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Comment: @AlanBirtles: Thanks a lot. Is the version of `libstdc++` bound to a version of `g++` or a version of `Ubuntu`? The relationship is not clear to me. It seems the include files of STL are in my case in '/usr/include/c++/7/' (and also in '/usr/include/boost/'), so apparently I have version 7 (is that used by both 'g++' and 'clang++'?).

Comment: it'd normally be the same version as g++ but I'm not sure it has to be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++17 execution policies are supported by GCC 10 and Clang 11.

Here is a demo example https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xahs5x1Kx

```
#include <execution>

int main()
{
    int a[] = {2,1};
    std::sort(std::execution::par_unseq, std::begin(a), std::end(a) );
    return a[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can confirm that it is supported by `g++-11.1`. In our case it was also necessary to install a new version of the Intel Thread Building Blocks library (TBB-2019), see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/55989883/3852630.

Comment: Even the current Clang 15 does not support C++17 execution policies. You can try that on the linked Godbolt Compiler website.

Comment: @mcserep, thanks, indeed the standard library `-stdlib=libc++` of Clang misses that support. But if Clang uses GNU standard library `-stdlib=libstdc++` then execution policies are supported as the demo shows.

Comment: is it supported for android NDK ?

Answer (score 2):

[poolSTL](https://github.com/alugowski/poolSTL) is a single-header implementation of some parallel C++17 algorithms, including sort:

```cpp
#include <poolstl/poolstl.hpp>

std::sort(poolstl::par, vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

It works on GCC 7 and versions of Clang missing native support.

There's also `pluggable_sort` to parallelize other fast sequential sorts, like [pdqsort](https://github.com/orlp/pdqsort):

```
poolstl::pluggable_sort(poolstl::par, vec.begin(), vec.end(), pdqsort);
```