# Error with std::execution::par while running Make on M1 mac

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, compiler-errors, c++17

I attempted to run my MakeFile generated with cmake but ran into the following error:

```
error: no member named 'par' in namespace 'std::execution'
        std::execution::par,
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/PyATMSim.dir/atmsim/atm_sim.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/PyATMSim.dir/all] Error 2
```

I'm on mac, so my default compiler is clang++.

Answers on various forums indicated that I needed at least C++17 which has parallel support. However, even after adding the following code to my cmakelist.txt I got the same error:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

Thanks in advance for the help as I am quite new to using Make and CMake.

Comment: according to this it doesn't look like apple clang supports that yet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77563340/4342498

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/17#C.2B.2B17_library_features, libc++ only has a partial implementation and apple hasn't implemented it at all