std::transform_reduce does not appear to run in parallel with std::execution::par
I have been experimenting with later versions of the C++ standard, in particular to better understand concurrent programming in modern C++.  I am developing on MacOS Sonoma on an Intel MacBook Pro.  I have been using gcc 13.2 (Homebrew), as the clang compiler that comes with Xcode Developer Tools does not implement the concurrency part of the C++17 standard.
I have not been able to get a speedup for an accumulation that should be trivially parallel. I have included a basic version of what I am trying to do. I have it running on Godbolt successfully here, but it only runs serially on MacOS.
This is my simplified test code:
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>


template <typename EP>
inline void timed_effort (
  const std::string& label,
  EP&& execution_policy,
  const std::ranges::iota_view<unsigned long, size_t>& interval,
  size_t quantum
) {
  using namespace std::chrono;
  auto start = system_clock::now ();
  
  auto result_par = std::transform_reduce (
      execution_policy,
      interval.begin (), interval.end (),
      0ul,
      std::plus {},
      [&] (size_t i) -> size_t {
          auto inc = std::ranges::views::iota (i * quantum, (i + 1) * quantum);
          auto sum = std::accumulate (
            inc.begin (), inc.end (), 0ul, 
            [&] (size_t acc, size_t x) -> size_t { 
              return acc + x * x * x;  
            });

          return sum;
      });
  
  auto end = system_clock::now ();
  duration <double, system_clock::period> time = end - start;
  std::cout << label << " = " 
            << result_par << " in " 
            << duration_cast <milliseconds> (time).count () 
            << " ms." << std::endl;
}


int main (int argc, char* argv []) {
  using namespace std::chrono;

  std::cout << "Testing " << std::thread::hardware_concurrency() << " execution cores." << std::endl;

  auto length = 10000000000ul;
  auto split = 5ul;
  auto quantum = length / split;
  auto interval = std::ranges::views::iota (0ul, split);

  timed_effort (
    "Parallel execution",
    std::execution::par,
    interval,
    quantum
  );
  
  timed_effort (
    "Sequenced execution",
    std::execution::seq,
    interval,
    quantum
  );
  
  return 0;
}

I wrote a CMakelists.txt for setup and build:
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.27)

project (
  example

  VERSION 1.0
  LANGUAGES CXX
)

message(status "Setting GCC flags and making sure we really have a gcc compiler.")

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "gcc-13")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/local/bin/g++-13")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=c++20 -O3 -pthread")
message(status "** CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS: ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

add_executable (
  example

  source/example.cpp
)

SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")

The function timed_effort should show a speed up when run with std::execution::par compared with std::execution::seq.  On my machine, the run times are very close (~4.6 seconds).
I have also run the code linked to Intel TBB (it was not clear to me whether or not this is still needed for standard algorithms to run in parallel on GCC 13 until I ran a Godbolt example).
Grateful for tips on what I am overlooking here.
EDIT - changed std::reduce to std::transform_reduce.

Did you check multiple cores are used, or at least that multiple threads are spawned?

@jérôme-richard, I have checked - only one thread is spawned.

@paleonix, the change is good.  The transform is the map component that should be parallelised - the original code did not make it available, but hid it in the reduction.  If you read it, it will make sense.

Sorry, you are right that the change is good, but that has less to do with the parallelism, just with the fact that previously your reduction operator was not even associative and commutative by approximation and therefore the results should have been non-deterministic (even without a parallel policy). I should have looked deeper into your code before making that comment. I didn't because I assumed that the issue comes from libstdc++ on Mac (Apple Silicon?) and not from your code. Turns out your code also had an issue.

Thanks again for your first comment, which made me adjust the question to something that makes sense.
I think that we ought to be able agree that std::plus is associative and commutes in its arguments, that the transform I propose should run in parallel without need for communicating without threads, and that running the parallel code on Godbolt using GCC 13.2 delivers a performance boost.
I don't want folk particularly distracted from the issue that I have, which is that it seems to be  difficult to get the MacOS version to generate threads.

That is why I removed the previous comments when they were no longer applicable. std::plus<size_t> is fine for a reduction, yes.

I personally have the same issue on a Ubuntu 24.04 with GCC 13.2. No new threads are apparently created and the parallel version is thus not parallel (it does not run at the same speed as the sequential version strangely). I followed the advises in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031060 (so I linked tbb) but no change... Note that the program takes 0 ms with Clang which is apparently able to completely optimize it out. Note that you can use OpenMP as an alternative is to that (it is more flexible and often more efficient though operations like parallel sorts are not provided).
