# Automatically point to tbb when installed without sudo

Tags: c++, linux, installation, compilation, tbb

I'm trying to install tbb without sudo access. I followed [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10769131/12146671), which work. However, is there any way to automatically point the linker to tbb without having to include `-I$TBB_INCLUDE -Wl,-rpath,$TBB_LIBRARY_RELEASE -L$TBB_LIBRARY_RELEASE -ltbb` with every compilation command?

Comment: Aren't you using some kind of build system?  Or at least a shell script.

Comment: @PaulSanders - No, if I try to use `make`, it trys to install to the root directory, which I do not have permission to edit. Hence this approach

Comment: Oh, OK.  Perhaps you can tweak their Makefile before you invoke it.

Comment: use the "tbbvars.sh" scripts to set your environment variables. For example,  go to the directory where the library was built and use "source tbbvars.sh" to set tbb environment variables.